# EditText first charset must be not 0

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want my `EditText` to be number value and not beginning with `0`, for example:

- If i enter `123`, its OK
- If i enter `0123` its an Error.

This is what i've done:

```
if(editText.getText().toString().charAt(0) == '0' ) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry firs charset must be not 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But it is working only when i click on button(`setOnClickListener`).

How i can check this before click button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `TextChangedListener`.

`TextChangedListener` Adds a `TextWatcher` to `EditText` and call each time whenever this `EditText's` text changes.

You want your edittext not to start with "0". so assign `TextChangedListener` to `EditText` then check event of typed character.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable mEdit) {
         if(mEdit.toString().length() > 0&& mEdit.toString().charAt(0) == '0' ) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First letter must not be 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Comment: You must check the string length before calling `charAt()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to your `EditText`

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

             if( (s.length()> 0) && (s.toString().charAt(0) == '0') ) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry first charset must be not 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

          }

          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
       });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   youredittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable mEdit) 
    {
        text = mEdit.toString();
         if(text.charAt(0) == '0' ) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry firs charset must be not 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this :

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length()>0 && s.charAt(0) == '0') {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry firs charset must be not 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

implement your activity with android.text.TextWatcher

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(this);

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   if(editText.getText().toString().charAt(0) == '0' ) { 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry firs charset must be not 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
    } 
}
```